# Html hide scrollbar bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So far i have a transparent `scrollbar`.

[image]

But there is a ugly white rectangle in the right corner which i would like to make transparent.

I also would like to hide the `bar` of the `scrollbar` so that only the `thumb`is visible and the `bar` is visible

- only while scrolling
- never

I would prefer a pure `Css` solution, however if this is not possible `js/jquery` is also ok.

**Css:**

```
.transparentScroll::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
}

.transparentScroll::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.transparentScroll::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: transparent;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

**Html:**

```
<div class="transparentScroll">
    <table>
        ...
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Is your goal to make them work similar to how OSX does?

Comment: I am not sure how OSX does it